# When rigging the character verticels are flipping (solved)

Tags: mesh, rigging, vertices, weight-painting, vertex-groups

So I don't know what did I do wrong when I do the rig or something but it just doesn't works correct.

screenshot:[image: here]

anyone knows how to  fix this problem?

edit: I deleted the download link because the problem is solved. (but If you have it please don't use it for any work hehe)

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots ıdk If you saw the comment lol

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader for images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: okay then I'll do that on my next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have two identical meshes in the same object, go in *Edit* mode and check out (use <kbd>L</kbd> to select a whole mesh), one is correctly rigged (at least it seems) and the other one not. Delete the bad one.